# Cannot save civivolunteer project

Tags: civivolunteer

I have CiviVolunteer installed on WordPress and have been using it without any issues until this morning when each attempt to save a project led to the following error message:
'A technical problem has occurred
Your submission was not saved. Resubmitting the form is unlikely to resolve this problem. Please contact a system administrator.'

Comment: Thanks for your post.  It would be helpful if you could edit it to provide the versions of CiviCRM, CiviVolunteer and WordPress that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After enabling debugging I saw that the civicrm_volunteer_project table was missing the title field.

There is an alter query in this file that did not run correctly for me as it failed on removing the foreign key.

`extensions/org.civicrm.volunteer/sql/volunteer_upgrade_2.0.sql`

Modified version (though you should run your own tests):

`ALTER TABLE`civicrm_volunteer_project
`ADD`title`VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  COMMENT 'The title of the Volunteer Project'
  AFTER`id`,
ADD`description`TEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
  COMMENT 'Full description of the Volunteer Project. Text and HTML allowed. Displayed on sign-up screens.'
  AFTER`title`,
ADD`loc_block_id`INT(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
  COMMENT 'FK to Location Block ID'
  AFTER`is_active`,
ADD CONSTRAINT`FK_civicrm_volunteer_project_loc_block_id
  `FOREIGN KEY (`loc_block_id`)
  REFERENCES`civicrm_loc_block`(`id`)
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
ADD`campaign_id`INT(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
  COMMENT 'The campaign associated with this Volunteer Project.'
  AFTER`loc_block_id`,
ADD CONSTRAINT`FK_civicrm_volunteer_project_campaign_id
  `FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_id`)
  REFERENCES`civicrm_campaign`(`id`)
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
MODIFY`entity_table`varchar(64) NULL,
MODIFY`entity_id`int(10) NULL;`

Comment: Patch welcome matey!

Comment: Thank you! I was able to resolve the issue by resetting the defaults for the Configure Volunteer Settings.